# In Dockerfile, how to append a value to an environment variable that can exist in base image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Let's assume we have a `Dockerfile` like this:

```
FROM SomeBaseImage:Version

ENV MyVar="MyValue"
```

In case `SomeBaseImage` already has a value for `MyVar`, we usually copy that and set the new value in our `Dockerfile`. In our case we need to append to it. But this has a drawback:

In case a newer version of `SomeBaseImage` modifies the value of `MyVar`, we'll end up with a hard-coded value based on the older version.

Is there a way to access the environment variable from the base image (and then possibly append to it)?

P.S: From my understanding, `Arg` is not the answer. It allows access to arguments passed by the build command, not environment variables set in the base image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have access to and be able to append to `ENV` variables in Dockerfiles:

`ENV MyVar=${MyVar}-modified`

Test base Dockerfile, built with: `docker build -t base -f Dockerfile.base .`

```
# Dockerfile.base
FROM alpine:3.9
ENV Version=v1.0
```

---

Test child Dockerfile built with `docker build -t child -f Dockerfile.child .`

```
# Dockerfile.child
FROM base:latest
ENV Version=${Version}-alpha
RUN echo ${Version}
```

The build output showed that the `Version` variable was read from the base and added to in the child:

```
 ...
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                
 => [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/base:latest                                                                                    0.0s
 => [2/2] RUN echo v1.0-alpha                                                                                                0.0s
 ...
```